# table of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject. ONLY IN SERVER(android)

Tags: java, android, json

Sorry for my English. I made an application for android and tested it on a local server (vertrigo). Everything worked well, the data is passed without errors. But after moving the database and scripts on the server I'm having the devil's fault. The server is passed an array of data, writes:

> Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value

I tried to identify the problem, but I never got rid of this line. This error occurs only on the server on the local host's OK. Then I tried to use a different server. There are no errors, but the dataset is still not passed. I do not know why, please tell me where I'm wrong.

The following is a script to which I refer:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');  
    require 'db_connect.php';  
    $db = new DB_CONNECT();  

    $response = array(); 
    $response["qwestions"] = array(); 

    if(isset($_POST['TeachId']) && isset($_POST['TestId']) && isset($_POST['listArrayQuestions'])) { 

        //set value to array 
        $listArray = $_POST['listArrayQuestions']; 
        $list = json_decode($listArray, true); 

        $TeachId = $_POST['TeachId']; 
        $TestId = $_POST['TestId']; 

        //add all array in db 
        foreach ($list as $name) { 
            $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `qwestions`(`TeachId`, `TestId`, `Text`) VALUES ('".$TeachId."',  
                '".$TestId."', '".$name."')") or die(mysql_error()); 
        } 

        $response["success"] = 1; 
        echo json_encode($response);   
    } else { 
        $response["success"] = 0; 
        echo json_encode($response);    
    }
```

following code java, showing moments where I use an array and how to convey

```
       ....
        private SaveQuestions squestuins; //asyncTask
        private TextView saveQwestions; //text view. If onclick add questions
        private JSONArray jsonA; //JsonArray
        ....
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            //enother code
            //....
            saveQwestions = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.saveqwestions);
            squestuins = new SaveQuestions();
            jsonA = new JSONArray();
        }

        //if onclick send all questions in db
        saveQwestions.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        //this is i all edit text add in JSONArray
                        for(int i = 0; i < et.size(); i++) {
                            jsonA.put(et.get(i).getText().toString());
                        }
                     //i send teatcherId, teatcherIdPoll, editTextPollName in asynkTask
                    squestuins.execute(new String[]{teatcherId,                   
                              Integer.toString(teatcherIdPoll), 
                                    editTextPollName.getText().toString()});
                });
    //...
    //enother code
    //...
    private class SaveQuestions extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {//code}
    @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
              //this is class
              JSONParser operationLink = new JSONParser();

              ArrayList<NameValuePair> insertQuestions = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

    //i add all i need
    insertQuestions.add(new BasicNameValuePair("TeachId", params[0]));
                insertQuestions.add(new BasicNameValuePair("TestId", params[1]));
                insertQuestions.add(new BasicNameValuePair("listArrayQuestions", jsonA.toString()));

    //Then I put a check whether something jsonA. Yes, it contains displays the       //questions that I have entered
    for(int r = 0; r < jsonA.length(); r++)  {
                    try {
            Log.e("listArrayQuestions " + r + " " + 
                      jsonA.get(r).toString(), "save questions");
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

//and send
    try {
                operationLink.makeHttpRequest(quicklyCreatePollSecondStepURL, "POST", insertQuestions);

            }catch(Exception e) { Log.i("SaveQuestions", "jsonUpdate", e); }

            }

 protected void onPostExecute(Void s) {//code}
    }
```

**UPD:**

JSONParser class

```
 static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    // function get json from url
    // by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
    public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
            List<NameValuePair> params) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {

            // check for request method
            if(method == "POST"){
                // request method is POST
                // defaultHttpClient
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params, HTTP.UTF_8));

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();

            }else if(method == "GET"){
                // request method is GET
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
            }           

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
```

**UDP**

if i change in class **JSONParser class** line:

```
 return jObj;
```

to

```
 return new JSONObject(json.substring(json.indexOf("{"), json.lastIndexOf("}") + 1));
```

i have success = 1, but still the error

> 03-07 18:21:10.304: E/JSON Parser(20838): Error parsing data
>   org.json.JSONException: Value

Comment: what is the response you get?

Comment: @Fahim i get "success":0 and error Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <br><table of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Comment: "<br><table" looks like you are trying to parse and invalid string, this may happen if server configuration is different (same paths may not work for instance), this may cause server to throw errors in the form of HTML. Make sure you know exactly what data is going out and in your android app. Try http://www.charlesproxy.com/ to sniff the messages..